# Permitting params in rails when form references multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models. The two I am having trouble with (recipe and ingredient) each have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with the other. The form seems to be getting all the information I ask for, but I can't seem to get the name attribute of the ingredient into my permitted params.

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe, :url => create_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :category %>
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c|[c.title, c.id]}) %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title%>

<%= f.label :instruction %>
<%= f.text_area(:instruction, size: "50x10") %>

<%= f.fields_for :indgredient do |i| %>
    <%= i.label :name %>
    <%= i.text_field :name %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

Relevant action in Recipes Controller:

```
def create
    safe_params = params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction,  
                                                 :category_id, {ingredient: :name})
    @recipe = Recipe.new(safe_params)
    @recipe.save
    @recipe.ingredients.create(name: safe_params[:name])
    render body: YAML::dump(safe_params)
end
```

What the YAML dump gives me:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
title: foo
instruction: bar
category_id: '1'
```

Code for models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  belongs_to :category
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

the `create` method does create a new ingredient, but the name is nil. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post your models code in the question?

Comment: Yes can you please code of models. This would help us identifying the issue.

Comment: maybe there is a typo in indgredient? `f.fields_for :indgredient` should be `f.fields_for :ingredient`

Comment: I fixed that typo and will add the code for the models now

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients` in the model of `Recipe` ?

Moreover there is a gem to handle nested forms called `cocoon`.

You can read this article which is explaining exactly what you are trying to do. 
https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/

Comment: I did include that in the model (just now added to model code). I will definitely check out cocoon. Thanks Hassan!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change `<%= f.fields_for :indgredient do |i| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>`.

And change the `new` and `create` actions like below

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @recipe.ingredients.build
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(safe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
def safe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction, :category_id, ingredients_attributes: [:name])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to `@Pavan`'s answer, you have to remember that Ruby is building *objects* (it's an [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language), and as such, whenever you pass associated data, you have to refer to the *objects* Ruby has in memory.

In your case, you're trying to create new `Ingredient` objects through `Recipe`:

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

... thus, you need to reference *`ingredients`*:

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do ... %>
```

--

You also want to make sure you're only processing the `Recipe` object in your `create` action:

```
def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new safe_params
    @recipe.save
end

private

def safe_params
   params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :instruction, :category_id, ingredients_attributes: [:name] )
end
```

Comment: This is really helpful. One question though - I left `ingredient` singular in the `f.fields_for :ingredient do |i|` line and it seems to be working fine. Multiple people have told me it should be plural. Any thoughts on why it is working?

Comment: You should look at your params, if it's coming back with `ingredient_attributes`, then it's good. I won't say anything until you confirm the response, though